# Не работает controlleras в directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

шаблон :

```
<div style="border: solid 1px black; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 10px;">

    <h1>name: {{userCardController.Users.name}}</h1>
    <h2>phone: {{userCardController.Users.phone}}</h2>
    <h2>address: {{userCardController.Users.address}}</h2>
    {{userCardController | json}}

</div>
```

Если убрать в шаблоне userCardController, то все заработает

```
function userCard() {
  var userCardDir = {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'userCard.html',
    controller: userCardController,
    controllerAs: 'userCardController',
    scope: {}
  };


  return userCardDir;
}

userCardController.$inject = ['$scope','Users'];

function userCardController($scope, Users) {
  $scope.Users = Users;
}

angular.module('userCard')
  .service('Users', Users);

function Users() {
  return {
    name: 'Vitaliy',
    phone: '380938891341',
    address: 'Mishugi 12'
  };
}
```

Comment: можешь сделать комплексный пример который можно запустить? тут в сниппете ли на [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная ошибка в том, что при использовании синтаксиса *controllerAs*, чтобы поля были доступны во view через имя контроллера, их надо добавлять в сам контроллер, используя *this*.

```
function userCardController($scope, Users) {
  this.Users = Users;
}
```